# JSON Data is Enclosed in Brackets Why?

Tags: php, json

my JSON data comes back enclosed in brackets for example: `[{"cust_id":"109"}]`. Why is that?
I've tried `mysql_fetch_row` and `mysql_fetch_object`. Do I need to substring to remove the brackets?

Also, how can I display a JSON object in javaScript? In Firebug, if I hard-code the JSON
data, I see a value as JSON, but alert() won't show it.

Thank you.

```
 $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 5):

That means an array consisting of excactly one element.

Comment: To expand, if it had multiple elements, it would look something like this: `[{"cust_id":"109"},{"cust_id":"110"},{"cust_id":"111"}]`

Comment: Does this mean I should substring out the brackets so that mydata returned to my javaScript is delimited by {...}? and why does json_encode delimit it's output with brackets if braces delimit an object - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The brackets indicate an array in JavaScript. If you only want one item you have to encode the first (and single) entry of your array specifically:

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
{
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you.  How can I print the data to my page?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. echo json_encode(...) already outputs the JSON data to the page.

Comment: But when I try to display the returned data from the page containing javaScript, (jQuery) I don't see anything...  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "call_ajax_query.php",
     data: {suite_no: suite},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
     $('#output').html(data);
    
      alert( "Data : " + data );
     }
   });

Answer (score 3):

Because it is JSON format syntax. More about it on: http://www.json.org/